# My question was edited and its meaning completely changed

Tags: discussion

[The link to the question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/231/irc-client-compliant-with-elementary-oss-hig)

So, as you can see from the URL, I was originally asking for an IRC client. Then, it was edited to change the word `IRC` to `Internet Chat` in the text of the question. Then it was changed again - the question title had `IRC` changed to `Chat`. Finally, I rolled the question back.

Now there's a big difference between asking for a general chat client and an IRC client. General chat client like Telepathy and Pidgin have implemented 10+ chat services. I asked for a client that supports only one service. Therefore, the meaning of my questions was *completely* changed (broadened actually) without any explanation what so ever.

Please be careful the content isn't changed when you edit.

Comment: http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/32/3